# The permissions granted to user 'MYDOMAIN\ryanhayes' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

Tags: permissions, reporting-services, reports

I'm getting several users getting access denied for some SSRS reports that are in a reports directory in SharePoint 2010.  I have a single sharepoint group with all users in it so all users have the same level of permissions (as an example I'll use *testaccount* and *ryanhayes* as account examples where testaccount is a domain account and ryanhayes is a domain account that is set up as a sharepoint administrator).

*ryanhayes* has full access to the reports and can run them and view the results.

*testaccount* has the same level access as they are both in the same group for the report library, but when trying to view a report, the user is greeted with the error:

> The permissions granted to user
>   'MYDOMAIN\ryanhayes' are insufficient
>   for performing this operation.
>   (rsAccessDenied)

SSRS is set up in SharePoint integrated mode.

The permissions of the group on the reports directory is (overkill, I know, but I've been working on this for about a day now):

> Full Control, Design, Contribute, Read, View Only

Again, the sharepoint admin account has the same level access (full) as everyone else in the group, but can view the report with no problem, while others get the insufficient permissions message.

What/where do permissions need to be granted to allow everyone in the group to be able to run the SSRS reports?  Is this a permission setting at the SharePoint level?  Central admin?  SSRS or SQL?  Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding that group to have access to the datasources used by the reports fixed the problem.  It worked for my account because as SharePoint admin I had access to the library that contained the datasources.

Comment: Thanks Ryan - Giving access to the data connection source "library in SharePoint" solved the issue